# Cordova 3.6.0 upgrade

Tags: cordova-plugins

After upgrading to Cordova 3.6.0 , the config.xml is not getting copied to res/xml.
This is causing my plugins not to be found.

I read somewhere, that in 3.6.0 plugins can be registered in code, but found no further documentation.

Greatly appreciate if you have any info.

Answer (score 0):

To show `assets/www` or `res/xml/config.xml`,

go to:
    Project -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters

And delete the exclusion filter.

You may see two www folders & 2 config files.
1. inside assets like assets/www and  www in main folder with arrow.
2. inside res/xml and in main folder with arrow.

Don't worry for the files and folders with arrow as they are just link to main www folder of cordova application root. So ignore them unless you re build through CLI and make changes to the assests/www and res/xml/config.xml for any changes you want.

This must work. I have done it.It's Working.